# Is $\mathbb{P}(A):=\lim_{N\to\infty}\max_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{\pi(n)}\#\{\text{primes }p\leq n,\ p\in A\}$ a Probability Measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm taking a class in probability, and we had a question which was to prove or disprove that
$$\mathbb{P}(A):=\lim_{N\to\infty}\max_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{\pi(n)}|\{\text{primes }p\leq n,\ p\in A\}|$$
is a probability measure. Here $\pi(n):=|\{\text{primes }p\leq n\}|$ is the prime counting function. I know
$$\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})=\lim_{N\to\infty}\max_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{\pi(n)}|\{\text{primes }p\leq n\}|=1,$$
and clearly $\mathbb{P}(A)\in[0;1]$ for any $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. But for additivity, I can only get to
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(A\sqcup B)&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\max_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{\pi(n)}|\{\text{primes }p\leq n,\ p\in A\sqcup B\}|\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\max_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{\pi(n)}(|\{\text{primes }p\leq n,\ p\in A\}|+|\{\text{primes }p\leq n,\ p\in B\}|)
\end{align}
and in general the maximum of sums need not be equal to the sum of the maxima, so I'm beginning to suspect this is not satisfied. I'm not sure how to prove it though, so could someone help me either way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variation on the [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density), and as with the natural density it fails to be a probability measure because it is not countably additive: $\mathbb{P}$ of any individual prime is $0$, but $\mathbb{P}$ of the entire set of primes is $1$.

Comment: Actually it's not even finitely additive.